# How do i convert a column of dates stored as text to date values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, schematiq

I am importing a CSV file (it has 849999 rows in it) with `=tbl.ImportDelimited(file.OpenText(*path*))` and trying to filter `=tbl.Filter(*table*, "Date", ">"&G11)` - where `G11` is a date - what is happening is that it is converting the date column to text and will not filter is there a way to force it to recognise that column as dates?

I tried to overwrite the column with `=tbl.CalculateColumn(*table*, "Date", DATEVALUE(), "Date")` but received the following error:

[image: date convert error]

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, it looks like the column of dates is being imported as text from the file, so filtering using > won't work because the value is actually text even though it looks like a date.

To convert text to date, you can use the DATEVALUE() function, but it needs to be passed to tbl.CalculateColumn() as a text snippet. In your example, you are actually calling DATEVALUE() and passing the result to tbl.CalculateColumn().

You should find that the following change to your formula will successfully convert the text values to dates:

```
=tbl.CalculateColumn(table, "Date", "DATEVALUE")
```

Passing `"DATEVALUE"` as the `function` argument is an example of the short-form snippet syntax. I've also omitted the `resultColumn` argument, since if you don't specify it, Schematiq overwrites the value of the input column. The following formula is longer, but exactly equivalent:

```
=tbl.CalculateColumn(table, "Date", "x => DATEVALUE(x)", "Date")
```

As you can imagine, there are many different Excel formulas you could use to convert from text to date. If you know the exact format you're expecting, something similar to this would also work fine:

```
=tbl.CalculateColumn(table, "Date", "x => DATE(RIGHT(x, 4), MID(x, 4, 2), LEFT(x, 2))", "Date")
```